# ASP.NET Telerik TreeView node cursor

Tags: asp.net, treeview, telerik, cursor

How do we set the hand cursor for a plain text node in a Telerik RadTreeView? This is an ASP.NET web app. We are just looking for a quick answer. Didn't see this posted here or on their site or in their docs clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe each node can have a css class set to it.  Then you just define your CSS class as follows

```
.plainTextNode {cursor:pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Their docs give a list of the CSS selectors you should know for applying your own CSS rules. [Here's the link](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tree_appearancecssselectors.html). Looks like you can achieve the desired effect with the following rule:

```
.rtHover { cursor: pointer; }
```

EDIT: the code above will apply to all RadTreeNode elements, regardless of their type. If you'd like to apply a specific style to certain RadTreeNode elements, set their CssClass property, and use that in conjunction with the above rule:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .rtHover .customPointer { cursor: pointer; }
</style>

<telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <telerik:RadTreeNode CssClass="customPointer" Text="Node 1" />
        <telerik:RadTreeNode Text="Node 2" />
    </Nodes>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```